# Best way to replicate an impala table

Tags: hive, hdfs, parquet, impala

I have some impala tables that were created under `tables/dir1/`. The the underlining format is parquet files in HDFS. There's a need to reproduce this table under another folder `tables/dir2/`. The reason being users of `dir1` do not have access to `dir2`. Both table need to exist and function. Wondering what would be a good way to do this? Is it reasonable to use airflow to schedule another task to use the same ddl to create the same table under `tables/dir2/` but point the file location to the same location as the original table?  Am I missing something here? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Use cloudera manager...

Comment: @KoushikRoy could you elaborate it a bit more? thanks.

Comment: every impala instance has coudera manager tool. Admin will probably has idea on it. it copies data from one place to another on filelevel. so its fast. https://docs.cloudera.com/cloudera-manager/7.4.1/index.html#:~:text=Cloudera%20Manager%20is%20a%20component,provides%20an%20overview%20of%20CDP.

Comment: does this answer your question so i can mark it as answer?